# Hibernate using IN and LIKE clause together

Tags: sql, hibernate

I have the follow hibernate code,

```
session.createQuery("from Car as car where car.keywordName like :keyword").setString("keyword", keyword ).list();
```

which takes in a keyword with the following parenthesis %keyword% and return the list of cars which has contain the keyword. The keywords of a car is a long string which is comma delimited for e.g. for a car the keywords will be "luxury, spacious, honta, 4seater" and another statement

```
session.createQuery("from Car as car where car.carId IN (:idList)").setParameterList( "idList", idList ).list();
```

which returns the list of cars from a list of id. I having been trying to combine the two clauses like and IN together to returns a list of cars from a list of keywords instead of just a single keyword.

Would appreciate if someone can shed some light. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to dynamically create a query to create something like

```
select car from Car car 
where car.keywordName like :k1 
or car.keywordName like :k2
or car.keywordName like :k3
...
```

The best tool to do that is the [Criteria API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria-narrowing) (See the third code snippet, using a disjunction, for an example of a list of restrictions seperated with `or`).

Comment: Thanks alot! I think it must have been the late night sleepiness. but you got me there!