# How to use multiple LIKE '%keyword%' in Sping JPA on same column?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am able to search for a keyword in a column using

```
List<Application> findByProposalContainingIgnoreCase(String keyword);
```

How can I achieve the same using a list of keywords?

For example:

```
List<Application> findByProposalContainingIgnoreCase(List<String> keywords);
```

**UPDATE:**

If it is not possible to do so, is the below way effective:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationService applicationService;

List<Application> applications = new ArrayList<>();

for (String keyword : keywords) {
    applications.addAll(applicationService.findByProposalContainingIgnoreCase(keyword));
}
```

Comment: @JaiDixit usually you should not do programmatically something that could be achieved with sql.

Comment: That defeats the whole purpose of the the spring repositories... plus you can't pass in a list in a like statement.

Comment: @dbl as far as I know sql does not support combining LIKE and IN

Comment: @dbl that again defeats the spring repository method that he is trying to use. Yes he could create a query object and crafting it as needed, but in this context he is trying to use the spring repository methods.

Comment: Current approach isn't the one you are looking for. Consider using the Criteria Api as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18553004/hibernate-using-in-and-like-clause-together#answer-18553077

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible as normal sql cannot do it either. The use of the word 'like' implies searching for all the possibilities that contain the keyword provided. In your case you'd have to string multiple contains statements together like

```
List<Application> findByProposalContainingIgnoreCaseOrProposalContainingIgnoreCase(String keyword1, String keyword2);
```

You might be better of doing the `in`keyword for your list

```
List<Application> findByProposalIn(Set<String> proposals);
```

The problem arises though that now you would have to add both uppercase and lowercase of the proposal to the set as it might not be case sensitive, and it will look for the exact matches not part of the word. Its not ideal but I think it'll work for what you're trying to do.

**UPDATE**

You're answer by adding the for loop would suffice for what you need.

Comment: The question here is how to combine LIKE and IN operators. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Comment: I can not agree for either of the options you proposed. First of them limits the count of the given strings, while the second one requires the full length string rather than just a piece of it.

Comment: I stated that in my answer and as I've stated before you cannot pass a list of items into a like statement in normal sql thus you have to chain along multiple `contains` statements. If you're going to critique my answer and downvote it provide your own answer.

Comment: @locus2k, is this a good solution? will this effect performance?

Comment: @Abhilash it might depends on how many words are in your keyword list and how vague each keyword is. You might get duplicate results as well. If you have one keyword that is like `hello` and another that is `he` it would return the same results. Having unique unrelated values in the list should be fine.