# Spring Data JPA - How to implement LIKE search with multiple values on the same column

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql, criteriaquery, dynamic-queries

Lets say I've the following table,

**MOVIE_TITLE**

1. Batman Begins
2. Batman Returns
3. Return of the Jedi
4. The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King
5. Shakespeare in Love
6. Dead Poets Society
7. Deadpool
8. The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring

I'd like to implement a search on the movie title and pass comma separated values (search with multiple keywords)

**For example,**

**search text: Batman**
result: Records #1,2

**search text: Batman, Return**
result: Records #1,2,3,4

**search text: Lord, Love**
result: Records #4,5,8

Without looping for each of the keyword, can this be implemented in one call using the LIKE search (or something else) in Spring Data JPA?

Thanks

Comment: Spring JPA queries require a fixed SQL statement which, under the hood, would correspond to a single fixed prepared statement.  If you know the number of terms, then you can create such a statement.  Do you know the number of terms beforehand, or at least, do you know the maximum number of terms?

Comment: Tim, Lets say maximum of 5 keywords per search. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the information.  Also, if you could include your current Spring/SQL code, that would be helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use multiple LIKE '%keyword%' in Sping JPA on same column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52497673/how-to-use-multiple-like-keyword-in-sping-jpa-on-same-column)

Comment: This question has many good answers you can modify them for your case also. [Spring Data - Multi-column searches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25872637/spring-data-multi-column-searches)

Comment: Tim - Sorry I couldn't get back to you with the code. Specification led me to the solution. Appreciate the community here..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you have an entity like this

```
@Entity
public class Movie {
   @Id
   Long id;
   String title;

   //getters, setters ...
}
```

Then you need repository extends [JpaSpecificationExecutor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaSpecificationExecutor.html)

```
public interface MovieRepository
        extends JpaRepository<Movie, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Movie> {
}
```

and [Specification](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/Specification.html) utility class

```
public class MovieSpecification {
    public static Specification<Movie> titleContains(String searchWord) {
        return (root, query, builder) -> {
           Expression<String> titleLowerCase = builder.lower(root.get("title"));
           return builder.like(titleLowerCase, "%" + searchWord.toLowerCase() + "%")
        }
    }
}
```

Usage on service layer:

```
MovieRepository repository;

public List<Movie> getMoviesWhereTitleContainsAnyWord(List<String> words) {
    if(words.isEmpty()) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    Specification<Movie> specification = null;   
    for(String word : words) {
       Specification<Movie> wordSpecification = MovieSpecification.titleContains(word);
       if(specification == null) {
           specification = wordSpecification;
       } else {
           specification = specification.or(wordSpecification);
       }
    }

    return repository.findAll(specification);
}
```

The more words you pass to the method the slower your query become due to multiple `or` clauses.

Comment: Thanks much Alex. This is pretty much what I was looking for. Also, the link shared by Eklavya helped me with the solution. One thing that I forgot to mention was that I was writing the search using Kotlin but the Java examples pretty much led me to the right path.

Answer (score 3):

In case you really don't want to combine multiple `LIKE`s in a loop, you can use Regular Expressions. However, there is no standard RegEx matching in T-SQL, but there are database-dependent solutions.

For example in Postgres you can use `~*` operator to match column against Regular Expression

```
sql> select 'The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King' ~* '(King|Queen|Princess|Lord|Duke|Baron)'
[2020-06-03 14:09:28] 1 row retrieved
```

And of course you have to do some preparations before query.

Repository layer:

```
@Query(value = "select * from Movie_table where movie_title ~* :term", nativeQuery = true)
public List<Object[]> findMovies(@Param("term") String term);
```

Service layer:

```
String searchText = "Lord, Love";
String searchTerm = Arrays.stream(searchText.split(","))
                    .map(String::trim)
                    .filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining("|", "(", ")"));

List<Object[]> movies = movieRepository.findMovies(searchTerm);
// ... code to convert `Object[]`-s to `Movie` entities ...
```

P.S. This solution is less elegant in compare to multiple `LIKE/OR` query

Comment: Thanks much Nikolai, but I like the solution based on CriteriaQuery and Specification better for the reasons you explained.